# Setting varaible/map key equal to arthemtic expression

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

New to elixir, and couldn't find an clear information regarding this. I was originally trying to create a new map, with one of the key-value pairs set equal to the result of the addition of 3 variables.

Kept getting errors so I tried just creating a temporary variable, but am getting the same issue.

Examples of what I've tried. (assuming score1, score2, and score3 are integers with values)

```
# Test 1
totalScore = score1 + score2 + score3

# Test 2
totalScore = score1 |> + score2 |> + score3

# Test 3
scorecard_params_updated =
   %{
      "age" => age,
      "name" => name,
      "totalScore" => score1 + score2 + score3
   }
```

Each of those methods failed, so what is the correct way of going about this?

This is a snippet of code that doesn't seem to work. This is the create function that my form is posting the data too.

```
def create(conn, %{"scorecard" => scorecard_params}) do

    %{"age" => age, "name" => name, "score1" => score1, "score2" => score2, "score3" => score3} = scorecard_params
    scorecard_params_updated =
      %Scorecard{
         :age => age,
         :name => name,
         :score1 => score1,
         :score2 => score2,
         :score3 => score3,
         :totalScore => score1 + score2 + score3
     }

...
```

The above code example gives me the error: "bad argument in arithmetic expression" for reference.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the errors you are getting? Your first test should be setting the `totalScore` variable fine. The second won't work because that isn't how pipes work (`totalScore = score1 |> Kernel.+(score2) |> Kernel.+(score3)` if you really wanted to do it using pipes). The third should work as well, setting the `scorecard_params_update` variable.

Comment: Your issue is probably with the `score1` 2, 3 since test 1 and 3 should work

Comment: I just edited the question to include the code snippet that's not working, the context, and the error I'm receiving. I updated the code to include the struct I'm trying to work with as well. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your arguments come as a params from HTTP Request, they are strings, so you have to convert them before performing addition.

You could try naive approach like this:

```
def create(conn, %{"scorecard" => scorecard_params}) do

    %{"age" => age, "name" => name, "score1" => score1, "score2" => score2, "score3" => score3} = scorecard_params
    score1_int = String.to_integer(score1)
    score2_int = String.to_integer(score2)
    score3_int = String.to_integer(score3)

    scorecard_params_updated =
      %Scorecard{
         :age => age,
         :name => name,
         :score1 => score1_int,
         :score2 => score2_int,
         :score3 => score3_int,
         :totalScore => score1_int + score2_int + score3_int
     }
...
```

Please make sure you read [`String.to_integer/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#to_integer/1) documentation to understand what problems might happen if it can't parse provided string as integer. Alternatively, you could take a look at [`Integer.parse/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Integer.html#parse/2) how it deals with invalid input.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked, I didn't realize the HTTP request params where strings. Thanks!